# How to force R Studio to use Viewer Pane for GoogleVis

Tags: r

Trying to use gvisTimeline from googleVis, but I'd like the plots to be shown in the Viewer Pane.

From what I can gauge from here (http://www.r-bloggers.com/display-googlevis-charts-within-rstudio/) it looks like the Viewer pane should be the default, but mine is showing up in the browser.

I did find this support article (https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane) but am unclear how to apply it to my specific need of using gvisTimeline.

ex:

```
    library(googleVis)  
    dat <- data.frame(Stn=device.positions$StationName,Idnt=device.positions$Ident,start=as.POSIXct(device.positions$Start),end=as.POSIXct(device.positions$End))
    timeline <- gvisTimeline(data=dat, rowlabel="Stn", barlabel="Idnt", start="start", end="end")
    plot(timeline)
```

where device.positions is a basic data table

Comment: Need to see your code to be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you plot the googleViz object you need to pass this as an option

```
plot(object, browser=rstudio::viewer)
```

Comment: Per a deleted answer to this question, you may have to use `plot(object,browser=rstudioapi::viewer)` depending on your version of R Studio.